# Sum of a geometric series $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone explain why $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{3^k}$?

I know the formula for the sum from n=1 to infinity, but what if I substitute n=1 with n=k?

Comment: The *correct* answer is $\frac1{3^k}\cdot \frac32$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. Perform the *change of index* $m=n-k$ to get
$$
\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{n-k+k}}=\frac{1}{3^k}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^m}
$$ then evaluate the latter series.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: (actually, you should make the lower bound $m=1$, as per the OP mentioning they know how to do that specific case already)

Comment: I don't understand the second equality?

Comment: @SidCaroline The new index is $m=n-k$, then when you see $n-k$ you can replace it with $m$, obtaining $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{n-k+k}}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{m+k}}=\frac{1}{3^k}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^m} $$